# Are there any known issus opening a QGIS Desktop project on Android?

Tags: qgis, android

Does anyone else have trouble when they try to open a project which was worked on in the QGIS desktop version 1.8 (I understand this is the most up to date version for the desktop) and try and open it up and work on it in the Android version of QGIS (I understand the most up to date version is 1.9).

Is it possible to have projects that work in both the desktop and Android version or could the problem be that the original project is in an earlier version?

Comment: Try the weekly (QGIS 1.9) for Desktop http://qgis.org/downloads/weekly/ this should be compatible with the Android Version.

Comment: Could you specify exactly what kind of problems you are experiencing? Some details about the nature of the project file would be helpful too. Have you tried with a really simple project with just one layer, or is it really complex?

Answer (score 1):

Projects are forward compatible. so a 1.8 project should open with no or minor issues in 1.9 and 2.0.

Comment: Do you have specific experience with opening QGIS projects in the Android version? At QGIS.se we do need answers to contain some detail, and (for a very short answer) some references to source material!

Comment: @Simbamangu, I'm the developer of the android version of QGIS, so I was just sharing the current state of things. Hope this still helps

Comment: Hi Marco - am an thankful, enthusiastic user (and occasional donor) of Android QGIS - should have noticed the name! Worth mentioning your qualifications in the answer as a 'reference'.

Answer (score 0):

In my case all I did was assemble all of the files used by a project into one directory on the PC, together with the QGIS project file. I then transferred a copy of the directory to an SD card, plugged this into the Android tablet and opened the project.

In your case, depending on your hardware, you might have to use a different method of getting a copy of the project directory out of your PC and into the Android device.

N.